# Looking for a free source code analyzer (Function depedency tree)

Tags: c++, c, code-analysis

Does anybody know where I can find a utility/application running on Windows that analyses C source and outputs a functional dependency tree?

What I'm looking for is something along these lines:

> PrintString->PrintCharacter->PrintByte->Printf

Comment: A pity it's not C++ + Linux: http://liveblue.wordpress.com/2009/08/21/gsoc-wrap-up-static-code-visualization-in-kdevelop/ :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's almost certainly overkill, but you can do this for C, C++, PHP, Java, C#, and more with [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/) (if you have [Graphviz dot](http://www.graphviz.org/) installed).  [Here's a page with a sample call tree](http://www-scf.usc.edu/~peterchd/doxygen/) generated by Doxygen/dot.

Doxygen runs on Windows fine, and can [output HTML and a few other formats](http://www.doxygen.nl/output.html).

Comment: You were damn fast to answer! I deleted my answer: I just added the remark that It is not directly a code analyzer: I mean it does not really understand the code but parses the functions, macros, structures correctly and displays also relations between files & headers (+classes in C++, Java, C#).

Comment: +1. Another advantage of using Doxygen for this is the opportunity to actually document your code...

Comment: If Doxygen does not actually understand the code, how does it handle calls that are the result of overloaded operators?

Comment: ... or indirect function calls?  We looked at a system of 250,000 functions.  Without a deep understanding the language and the specific code, a call to *foo() could go to literally hundreds of thousand targets, making the call graph useless.  (We built a points-to analyzer to help control this problem).

Answer (score 1):

Tools that read source but don't understand the programming language in a deep semantic sense can only give you an approximation of the call graph.  (What if a call occurs in a macro?  What if that call occurs inside a disabled preprocessor conditional?   What if the call is indirect?)
If this is good enough, and you really don't care to know about what indirect calls do, then tools like Doxygen and CScope will probably be helpful.

If you want an accurate call graph, you need a tool constructs one using full knowledge of the langauge.  Frama-C (see other answer) AFAIK is one, although I don't know how it handles macros and indirect calls.

Not free, but the [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit and its C front end](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit) have full C macro/preprocessor processing capability, and constructs call graphs for a system of files.  It specifically includes a points-to analysis in its call graph construction to give you a conservative approximation of where indirect function calls go.   See [example call graph](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/SampleCallgraph.jpg) with black arcs  (direct calls) and blue arcs (conservatively analyzed) indirect calls.

Answer (score 0):

Many tools produce this kind of call-graph. Doxygen may well have the most presentation options for the results, being a "literate programming" tool at its core.
The open source tool at http://frama-c.cea.fr/ produces call-graphs (also in the dot format) and tries to group the functions by "services" automatically: http://img23.yfrog.com/img23/8180/9il.png

Answer (score 0):

CodeInsight is a commercial editor that has the functionality of CTAGS/CSCOPE rolled in. It can display call tree graphs (and almost any other relationship) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Source Navigator seems to be in development again (latest release of SourceNav NG was in February of this year). Source Navigator can give you call trees, class dependencies, etc, etc. I have not tried the recent versions. Works on windows or X11.

http://sourcenav.berlios.de/